# How do set the probability of winning a prize, if the total awarded prizes is capped, but the number of participants can vary significantly

Tags: probability, gambling

I am writing a program meant to simulate a gambling game. I want to be able to set the total amount of possible winnings for each day. But I do not know the number of players I will have that given day.

Say I have 3 possible prizes: $\$1$, $\$5$ and $\$10$ and I want to give out a maximum of $100\$$ every day. I can have between 500 and 10000 players in any given day.

How do I configure the probability of winning each prize, so that a player playing early in the morning has approximatively the same change of winning as a player who plays in the evening?

Comment: Smart aleck response: have the probability be identically zero for all players.  That being said... consider the following two extreme scenarios that both begin the same way... three people log in in the morning and *noone else* logs in the rest of the day versus three people log in in the morning and a *trillion* people log in in the rest of the day.  You sound like you are wanting to decide on a probability for the third person *at the time of the third person's visit* that somehow changes its probability based on knowledge of future events which haven't happened yet.

Comment: At the time of the third person's visit, we have no way of distinguishing between these two cases.  It may be better to have the rewards be determined at the end of the day after we have seen all players for the day and can more fairly distribute., and let the login-reward prize be the prize from the previous day that the user logged in rather than the current day.  In order to make the experience less jarring, give new users a first time login bonus.

Comment: Choose a statistically improbable number of users as the "upper bound". Example, you say on average between 500 and 10000 players will play per day. So, set the "upper bound" to 100000. It is unlikely that you will have more than that. Now, set prizes assuming you have 100,000 users per day, and this will ensure that within a very high statistical likelihood, you will never go over the maximum of $100 in prizes per day, and in fact you are likely to go far under your maximum. Additionally, every player will have equal opportunity for prizes.